# Magento can't set free shipping for my shipping method (by promo rules)

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have my own shipping method with some logic.

```
//some logic
$method->setPrice($price);
```

When in admin panel in  promo rules i set free shipping for some condition, all other shipping method set to 0, but not may.
Help me please, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
 if ($request->getFreeShipping() === TRUE) {}
```